# bootstrap drop down menu not working when clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Every time I try to click the button for the drop down it just doesn't do anything, I know it's probably a simple mistake.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <title>Module 3 Solutions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
<body>

<!-- alllllll this in the bottom is the nav bar code
*****************************************************
*****************************************************
*****************************************************-->

<header>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-brand">Food LLC</div>

          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target= ".navHeaderCollapse">


          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>   
          </button>  


            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>


            </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>








</header>             

</body>            



<h1 id="text-center">Our Menu </h1>

<body>

<div id="C-title">Chicken</div>
<p>  
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
</p>


<div id="B-title">Beef</div>
<p>  
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
</p>


<div id="S-title">Sushi</div>
<p>  
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100% 
</p>




















  <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems, that you use couple <body></body> twice

Comment: Tnx Yes I did remove that but still didnt fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this structure :

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found My mistake!!!!!

On my index page Im using jquery-1.11 something outdated and wasent even downloaded into my JS folder I simply downloaded the current version jquery-3.1.1.min.js and BOOOOM!!!!!! problem fixed I have the dropdown menu for my menus!!!!!